# Adjusting function in C to perform one permutation at a time

Tags: c, function, permutation

I have an issue that feels very simple, but is apparently not simple enough. I require the below function to perform just one permutation so that I may use its values, before calling for another permutation if required. Right now, it permutes through all options until completion before each permutation can be checked, from just one call. Every alteration I've attempted breaks the function entirely, so some recommendations/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the function with demo variables:

```
int nums[4] = {0}, n = 4, index = 0; 
bool busy[4] = {false};

void next(int index, int nums[], int n, bool busy[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (!busy[i]) {
            nums[index] = i;
            busy[i] = true;
            next(index + 1, nums, n, busy);
            busy[i] = false;
        }
    }
    // Demonstrate permutation
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}
```

And here's how I'm attempting to utilize each permutation, where nums[] is the permuted array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfWords; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < wordLengths[i]; ++j) {
            sums[i] = (sums[i] * 10) + nums[charPosition(uniqueChars, words[i][j], numUniqueChars)];
        }
    }
```

I note that I've only included next() in the code, but that's enough to demonstrate my issue.

Thank you dearly for taking time out of your day for this.

Comment: Is the problem that the print statements in next() execute at each permutation and you would like to do something else instead of printing at that spot?  If so you could pass next() a function pointer for a callback that executes a function of your choice.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thank you very much for your answer. I imagine your solution is what I was looking for, although I've only begun learning about pointers, so I'll grapple with what you've recommended. I ended up calling a function within next(). Thanks again!